# VBA (EXCEL) String is cut out (is not printed all the sting)

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating generator for google VCF in VBA.
String is generated correctly (verified at watch) but all the string is not printed to file (string is cut out). String is also cut out when I  try to copy/ paste it from watch.

The only special characters in string is EOL (CHR(10)). 
String is cut out in the middle of word.

```
Sub ExcelTocsv()
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer
Dim googlestring As String
Dim mystring As String


iRow = Cells(2, 3)
iColumn = 55
' set a unique integer for the new
' text file
FileNum = FreeFile
' Save this vcf file on desktop
OutFilePath = VBA.Environ$("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MyContacts.VCF"
Open OutFilePath For Output As FileNum

With Sheets("Google")
While VBA.Trim(.Cells(iRow, 1)) <> ""
    googlestring = "Name,Given Name,Additional Name,Family Name,Yomi Name,Given Name Yomi,Additional Name Yomi,Family Name Yomi,Name Prefix,Name Suffix,Initials,Nickname,Short Name,Maiden Name,Birthday,Gender,Location,Billing Information,Directory Server,Mileage,Occupation,Hobby,Sensitivity,Priority,Subject,Notes,Language,Photo,Group Membership,E-mail 1 - Type,E-mail 1 - Value,Phone 1 - Type,Phone 1 - Value,Phone 2 - Type,Phone 2 - Value,Address 1 - Type,Address 1 - Formatted,Address 1 - Street,Address 1 - City,Address 1 - PO Box,Address 1 - Region,Address 1 - Postal Code,Address 1 - Country,Address 1 - Extended Address,Organization 1 - Type,Organization 1 - Name,Organization 1 - Yomi Name,Organization 1 - Title,Organization 1 - Department,Organization 1 - Symbol,Organization 1 - Location,Organization 1 - Job Description,Website 1 - Type,Website 1 - Value" & Chr(10)
    For iColumn = 2 To 56
        mystring = mystring & Cells(iRow, iColumn)
        If iColumn < 56 Then
            mystring = mystring & ","
        Else
            mystring = mystring & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next


' Start printing the data in above specified
' format of VCF file format
    Print #FileNum, googlestring
    Print #FileNum, mystring

    iRow = iRow + 1
Wend
End With
'Close The File
MsgBox "Total " & iRow - Cells(2, 3) & " Contacts are exported to VCF File. It is saved on your Desktop"
Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any special chars hidden in `myString` try using `instr` to see if there are

Comment: `Cells(iRow, iColumn)` should be proceeded with a sheet reference also.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All. Code is OK but I ran it through debug and stoped it with MsgBox (last but one line of code) that says Contact are saved (at this point I checked what is written). The last line is Close File. File was not closed and also not printed up to the end).

I moved msgbox to the last line of code to prevent this:))